# How to fnd if a given graph can be decomposed into claws?

Tags: c++, bipartite

I have given a graph where each vertex has exactly 3 edges.Now I have to find out If the graph can be decomposed into claws or not. I know, If the graph is bipartite graph, than it can be decomposed into claws, I can't understand, How claws are related to bipartite checking?

Comment: A bipartite graph could probably be decomposed into claws, but not every bipartite graph will have claws.  What do you mean "if the graph can be decomposed into claws"?  Are you trying to determine if there are claws in the graph?

Comment: a decomposition of a graph is a list of subgraphs such that each edge appears in exactly one subgraph in the list.

Comment: Then not every bipartite graph can be decomposed into claws.  The bipartite graph A - B cannot be decomposed into claws.